# How to advice developers after merging feature branch to master to enable git LFS (git)

Tags: bash, git, version-control, git-bash, git-lfs

**Details** :

- We are trying to migrate our repo to git LFS
- I have a branch that will enable git lfs, what I am doing is updating a .gitattributes file, and creating a tracker which in turn created pointers to track all the files that need to be part of the LFS
- Now I would have to advise the developers what they need to do once this feature branch is to merged into the default/master

**The problem that I need to understand?**

- Now what I have advised and found in general is before updating to the master/default, ie, rebasing to master/default, I told them to do the below for all the feature branches that they have which obviously till this point do not have the git lfs changes in them

```
brew install git-lfs (this will be system-wide)
git lfs install (this will be on the root directory of the repo, for each branch)
```

- Now for the devs, this will be a manual step, and they somehow want this to be automated for them, which I assume may be done through git hooks, or some other way so that they do not have to update every branch
  I am thinking of a plumbing bash command as such might do it? Is this feasible

```sh
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/); do 
    git lfs install "$branch"; 
done
```

**Update1**

- Seems the above does do `git lfs install` on all the branches that you have in your local history and does it in one time.
- But I would still want to know and understand what is `best` practice

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any need to run `git lfs install` in all branches – once you do `install` in a repo, it is set up permanently for that repo. From the help:

```
$ git lfs install --help
git lfs install [options]

Perform the following actions to ensure that Git LFS is setup properly:

* Set up the clean and smudge filters under the name "lfs" in the global Git
  config.
* Install a pre-push hook to run git lfs pre-push for the current repository,
  if run from inside one. If "core.hooksPath" is configured in any Git
  configuration (and supported, i.e., the installed Git version is at least
  2.9.0), then the pre-push hook will be installed to that directory instead.
```

Hooks are stored within the `.git` folder, so they are not affected when you check out a different branch.

Now, as you appear to be aware, if people have branches that are older than your merge of the new `.gitattributes` file, they would need to rebase those branches to pick up the changes and ensure the right files were treated as LFS ones. But this is not related to `git lfs install`.

Comment: ok, Let me ask you this, please tell me if I am unclear. 

- Let's not worry about `.gitattributes`, that will come  with `rebase`
- The devs will for sure, have a number of branches they are working on, and those will not have the `.git` hooks for `lfs` in them, unless and until he does `git lfs install`, in the root directory, do you mean to say - if they do a `git lfs install` in any of the branches the `.git` persists for all the branches by default? 
if the answer to the above is yes, then that is great, they do it once, and all `old` branches will have `lfs .git/hooks` in them .

Comment: @SandeepAnand: It really doesn't make sense to talk about the `.git` folder being in a branch or "persisting for all branches", because the `.git` folder *is the repository itself*. The repository contains the master copy of all the branches, and when you do a checkout, the appropriate files are copied out of the repository (the `.git` folder) into the working folder (usually the parent directory of the `.git` folder). Thus, when you put hooks in `.git/hooks`, such as with `git lfs install`, it doesn't matter what branch you're on, they will be equally accessible.

Comment: Sounds good, then I think we are good. I do not think `git lfs install` need to run on all branches, and a one time on any branch will be good to go.